# Passing big arrays efficiently between Flutter (dart) and its FFI (C/C++)?

Tags: flutter, ffi, dart-ffi

We are developing a "image editor" app using Flutter. Thus, we need to (1) show images on the UI, and (2) manipulate images using some algorithms in C/C++.

Flutter does have a FFI between dart and c/c++, but I do not know how to pass *big* arrays like images (e.g. can be  megabytes) *efficiently*?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experiments, now I have some code (in the production code!) passing around **array of 20MB size** between C and Dart. It *only takes several milliseconds* (just a rough estimation, but surely it does not take seconds).

Thus, my answer to my question is: *Just do it.* Memory copies seems to be quite cheap, and do not worry about it :)

---

**EDIT in 2022:**

Flutter does have have "zero copy" array transfer when going from native to Flutter side, via DartCObject. See the "ZeroCopyBuffer" feature in my library https://github.com/fzyzcjy/flutter_rust_bridge for an example of usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [asTypedList](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-ffi/Uint8Pointer/asTypedList.html) method, which works with alot of dart `Pointer` classes such as `Uint8Pointer`...

**Example** Usage:

```
Int32List l = myNativeCall().asTypedList(myListLength); //myNativeCall() returns a Pointer<Int32>
```

Note that the native memory should stay accessible as long as list l is going to be used.

You may want also to use [NativeFinalizer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-ffi/NativeFinalizer-class.html) when using this method to free the native memory when the corresponding dart object is garbage collected, to avoid memory leaks.